# Building adjacency matrix from delaunay triangle values

Tags: r, geometry, adjacency-matrix, delaunay

I have a large matrix containing 3D coordinates of points and I want to have the adjacency matrix of them using their delaunay triangulation results. To have their delaunay triangulation values I used 'geometry' package. To have an example of what I have, I prepared the below codes:

```
values<-rnorm(12,mean = 10, 5)

mat<-matrix(values,ncol = 3)

dimnames(mat)<-list(c("asd","qwe","rty","poi"),c("x","y","z"))

require("geometry")

delaunaynMat<-delaunayn(mat)
```

However, I could not find any proper function to build the adjacency matrix from delaunay results. Any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with the `DatabionicSwarm` package

```
> library(DatabionicSwarm)
> Delaunay4Points(mat, IsToroid=FALSE)
  1 2 3 4
1 0 1 1 1
2 1 0 1 1
3 1 1 0 0
4 1 1 0 0
```

Or wirh `deldir` (only for 2D):

```
> require(deldir) 
Loading required package: deldir
deldir 0.1-15
> set.seed(42) 
> x <- runif(6) 
> y <- runif(6) 
> dxy <- deldir(x,y) 
> ind <- dxy$dirsgs[,5:6] 
> adj <- matrix(0, length(x), length(y)) 
> for (i in 1:nrow(ind)){ 
+     adj[ind[i,1], ind[i,2]] <- 1 
+     adj[ind[i,2], ind[i,1]] <- 1 
+ } 
> adj 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    0    1    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1
[4,]    1    1    0    0    1    1
[5,]    0    1    1    1    0    1
[6,]    0    0    1    1    1    0
```

## EDIT

There's something weird. I need to flip the matrix of Delaauny4Points to get results consistent with `deldir`:

```
set.seed(42) 
x <- runif(6) 
y <- runif(6) 
dxy <- deldir(x,y) 
ind <- dxy$delsgs[,5:6] 
adj <- matrix(0, length(x), length(y)) 
for (i in 1:nrow(ind)){ 
    adj[ind[i,1], ind[i,2]] <- 1 
    adj[ind[i,2], ind[i,1]] <- 1 
} 
adj
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1    1    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    1    1
[4,]    1    1    0    0    1    1
[5,]    0    1    1    1    0    1
[6,]    1    0    1    1    1    0

> Delaunay4Points(cbind(x,y), IsToroid=FALSE)[6:1,6:1] # <- look
  6 5 4 3 2 1
6 0 1 0 1 0 1
5 1 0 1 1 1 0
4 0 1 0 0 1 1
3 1 1 0 0 1 1
2 0 1 1 1 0 1
1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: @Laurent Thanks a lot for your response. That was excellent. As my matrix contains 3D coordinates, I think the first solution works for me.

Comment: @minoo Unfortunately I'm not sure. Look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175867/error-with-delaunay4points-subscript-out-of-bound

Comment: @minoo If you're using Windows, you can try my package: https://github.com/stla/delaunayadjacency (currently it works on windows only)