# Error with Delaunay4Points: subscript out of bound

Tags: r, delaunay

I have this matrix:

```
v <- rbind(  c( -5, -5,  16 )  
           , c( -5,  8,   3 )  
           , c(  4, -1,   3 )  
           , c(  4, -5,   7 )  
           , c(  4, -1, -10 )  
           , c(  4, -5, -10 )  
           , c( -5,  8, -10 )  
           , c( -5, -5, -10 ))
```

And then:

```
> library(DatabionicSwarm)
Delaunay4Points(v, IsToroid = FALSE)

Error in UniqDelaunay[Uniq2DataInd, Uniq2DataInd] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Is it a bug ? Unfortunately there's no Github repo to fill an issue.

I've compared with another tool and the result should be:

```
[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]
[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1]
[0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1]
[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
```

Comment: Well, what debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: @Roland it works wirh `v[1:7]`. Weird. Otherwise I don't know what to do. I will try breakpoints.

Comment: The function gives an output if I remove `Points = Points[, 2:3]` from its code. But the result is not correct I think

Comment: @DJack This "works" but this is not the correct output (I've compared with another tool)